# Working with the random variable $\log X$ instead of $X$

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables

Suppose I have a positive stochastic process $X_t$. I'd like to compute certain properties about $X_t$, but suppose I can't and instead I can compute properties about $\log(X_t)$. Can I say anything about $X_t$ based on $\log(X_t)$?

For example, suppose $E\left[\log(X_t)^p\right] < K$ (i.e. the stochastic process has finite $p^{th}$ moment for all $p$). Is there a way to extend that to say something about $X_t$?

Or as another example, suppose I know the paths of $\log(X_t)$ are Holder-continuous. Can it be shown that the paths of $X_t$ are Holder-continuous as well?

My hunch is no only because $\log(x) < x$ so a lot of the inequalities that would be useful aren't necessarily true (e.g. Jensen's Inequality).

Answer (score 1):

well if exponentiation preserves a property then it will continue to hold. For example, $f$ holder cts implies that $e^f$ is so yes that property goes over.

Comment: Thank you for this. The main way I know how to show holder continuity is that the moments are finite. But now I can do that using logs. I still suppose however there's no way to justify that $E\left[ X_t^p \right]$ is bounded though

Comment: a log normal has all moments finite. However, its exp has no moments finite. i.e. exp of exp of normal.